# How do I reference Javascript function for div tag to add commas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a Javascript newbie ... and I've heard of jQuery, but don't have a clue how to use it, so please bear with my complete lack of knowledge here ... :)

I am dynamically importing information from an Excel database onto a website.  It works great, except that none of the numbers have commas - it's a formatting issue that I can't change at the source, so I need to change it in the website code.

The relevant HTML code looks like this:

```
<tr><td class="num">191025</td><td>Stuff</td><td class="num">$60</td></tr>
<tr><td class="num">184160</td><td>Other Stuff</td><td class="num">$15</td></tr>
```

I want to use Javascript (or jQuery - whatever works) to add commas to all existing "num" classes (so 191025 would appear as 191,025).

I have been poking around this site and others and found this site: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html which has this public domain code:

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Which seems great, and I added it to my existing external .js page that I reference within my html page.

However, the issue is now how do I use the code?  Looking at the examples on that page, it looks like I would have to do something like this:

```
<tr><td class="num">addCommas(191025)</td><td>Stuff</td><td class="num">$60</td></tr>
```

And that's just not realistic - there are hundreds of these numbers, and I just can't update each and every one of them individually.

I am certain that there's a way that Javascript (or jQuery?) can automatically apply coding to the existing "num" classes to insert commas ... but I have no idea how to go about it.  So, all of this bring me to my question: **How do I efficiently apply this (or other - better?) code to the div class so that commas are added?**

I *greatly* appreciate any help ... but please keep in mind my newbie-ness, and let me know what needs to go in the external .js sheet & what goes on the .html page.

Thank you!!

Comment: http://jqfundamentals.com/ is a good website for beginners.

Comment: Thank you, @jbabey - I will check that out and see if I can start making sense of the jQuery code I see.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution:

```
$('.num').each(function () {
    $(this).text(addCommas($(this).text()));
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

javascript solution (won't work in IE as it does not support [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName))

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
var textPropertyToUse; // cross-browser support

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    textPropertyToUse = 'textContent' in elements[i] ? 
        'textContent' : 
        'innerText';

    elements[i][textPropertyToUse] = addCommas(elements[i][textPropertyToUse]);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XpbJV/

Comment: IE does support `getElementsByClassName` starting with version 9. Also, IE8 supports `querySelectorAll`, so you could use that for greater compatibility.

Comment: ...but don't use `.innerText`. It's non-standard, doesn't have broad support, and terribly slow in some of the modern browsers that do support it. Only use it as a backup for IE8 and lower.

Comment: @amnotiam i'm never sure what to recommend instead of `innerText` if they're not using jQuery, what do you recommend?

Comment: The standard property is `.textContent`, but you'll need to revert to `.innerText` for IE8 and lower. So you'd need something like... `if ("textContent" in elements[i]) ... else ...`

Comment: ...or a good cross-browser solution *(in this situation)* is to work with the text node directly... `var tn = elements[i].firstChild; tn.data = addCommas(tn.data)`

Comment: @amnotiam updated. never even heard of `textContent` until now. thanks.

Comment: Use jquery and be happy. No more browser-specific-behavior-that-suc** :)

Comment: @devundef that is my personal solution, but some people are not so lucky :P

Comment: @devundef: There are people who come to this site, desperate for a solution because for the first time they're confronted with a situation where they can't use jQuery, and they're lost without it. Learn the DOM, and be well-rounded. Then choose when/where it makes sense to use jQuery.

Comment: @am not i am, I agree with you. Sadly browser vendors do not help us, especially MS. I confess to you that I forgot many workarounds that I've learned from the days when I used to create workarounds for IE and then for Firefox etc. After jquery/prototype/dojo I've never had back for the pure DOM. For me is too much annoying and verbose. But you're right. Because I know the DOM I can see what jQuery do for me. People who go direct on jquery can't see what is really going on and then they think jQuery is magical, what is not. But it is really usefull :)

Answer (score 1):

Execute this code on page load:

```
$(".num").each(function() {
   var self = $(this), text = self.text();
   self.text(addCommas(text));
});
```

Comment: How do I execute code on page load?  I tried this in the page header: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".num").each(function() {
   var self = $(this), text = self.text();
   self.text(addCommas(text));
});
}
</script>`

Comment: That's correct. If it is not working, check your browser console for errors in js.

Comment: Hmmm.  Could the fact that the page data is being loaded via php be causing a problem with the jQuery code?

Comment: @AmyB noop, is something else. Your browser console doesn't show anything? Is jQuery beeing reference before the this script?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple jQuery solution would be...

```
$(".num").text(addCommas);
```

...as long as you change your `addCommas` function signature to this...

```
function addCommas(i, nStr)
```

---

This will work because your `addCommas` would take the current text content as the second argument, and return the updated text content. That's how most of jQuery's iterator versions of their methods work.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/gprf6/

Comment: Looks wonderfully simple ... but where do I put it in my code so that it works?

Comment: @AmyB: Is this the only JavaScript on your page? If so, I wouldn't bother using jQuery. But either way, wrap it in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags, and  place in the `<body>`, just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: ...and make sure you've loaded the jQuery library.